# at.allow and at.deny precedence (in Ubuntu)?

Tags: account-restrictions, at

It's clear from documentation about cron that if `cron.allow` and `cron.den` both exist then `cron.allow` takes precedence and it is allowed.

What is the case for `at.allow` / `at.deny`?
Everywhere I've searched and checked does not say it explicitly.

I use Ubuntu.

Comment: At least on Bionic, I had to set owner to root:daemon and permissions 640 otherwise at.allow is ignored

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [FreeBSD](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=at) and [Solaris](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/816-5165/6mbb0m9ao/index.html) manuals are clear: if `at.allow` exists, `at.deny` is ignored. The Linux manual is slightly less explicit but the behavior is the same.

Despite the convergence of BSD and Solaris, this is not universal. On [AIX](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/aix/v7r1/index.jsp), if a user is listed in both `at.allow` and `at.deny`, then he cannot use `at`.

Comment: I use Ubuntu and I verified that yes, if both exist, allow takes precedence.